# Upload Collection of ViewModels containing IFormFile in Asp.Net Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a document service API written in ASP.NET Core Web API 2.1. This API currently accepts a ViewModel containing information for 1 file and then saves that file and information to the server. I want to add the ability to add multiple files, but I cannot get the `IFormFile` file to bind when uploaded as part of a collection.

```cs
/// The ViewModel being uploaded.
public class FileUploadDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}

/// Works perfect. All properties are bound to the fileUploadRequest object.
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add(FileUploadDto fileUploadRequest)
{
    /// Process

    return Ok();
}

/// All properties are bound to the objects in the collection, except for the File property.
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddRange([FromForm] IEnumerable<FileUploadDto> fileUploadRequests)
{
    foreach (FileUploadDto fileUploadRequest in fileUploadRequests)
    {
        //fileUploadRequest.File is null
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

I am testing this by using Postman, and uploading the content in the body, using form-data, as:

[0][Description]:Test (Type: Text)
[0][Name]:Test (Type: Text)
[0][File]:sample.txt (Type: File)

`multipart/form-data` is set in the content-type header.

UPDATE:
I've found a workaround by doing the following, but obviously this is not the best thing to do. I recognize the problem is that the files are not being bound to my ViewModels, but are being stored in the `Request.Form.Files` collection. I'm not sure how to work around that, though.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddRange([FromForm] IEnumerable<FileUploadDto> fileUploadRequests)
{
    var index = 0;
    foreach (FileUploadDto fileUploadRequest in fileUploadRequests)
    {
        //fileUploadRequest.File is null
        fileUploadRequest.File = Request.Form.Files[index];
        index += 1;
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up passing an additional property to specify the file index to use in the Request Form.

```cs
/// The ViewModel being uploaded.
public class FileUploadDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? FileIndex { get; set; }
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }
}

/// Works perfect. All properties are bound to the fileUploadRequest object.
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add(FileUploadDto fileUploadRequest)
{
    /// Process

    return Ok();
}

/// All properties are bound to the objects in the collection, except for the File property.
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddRange([FromForm] IEnumerable<FileUploadDto> fileUploadRequests)
{
    foreach (FileUploadDto fileUploadRequest in fileUploadRequests)
    {
        fileUploadRequest.File = Request.Form.Files[fileUploadRequest.FileIndex ?? -1];
    }

    return Ok();
}
```